# Conditionally assign unique values

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, max, worksheet-function

I have data, for example:

```
John Doe    MD      1
Ben Doe     PA       
Cal Doe     MD      1
Drum Doe    PA       
Egg Doe     NP       
Fun Doe     MD      1
```

So everywhere there's an `MD` I have an IF condition assigning the number 1.  But I want to isolate and pull all the names with a 1 consecutively. Example:

```
John Doe
Cal Doe
Fun Doe
```

I know I just have to have numeric values such as: john doe-1, cal doe-2, fun doe-3.

I'm having problem with the logic if someone can help I'll appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is in three columns (starting A2) then maybe:

```
=IF(B2="MD",MAX(C$1:C1)+1,"")
```